# How do I correctly cite the C++ standard or its drafts?

Tags: citations, software, code

For my bachelor thesis, I have to reference a lot to the various C++ standard documents, be it the original standard or some of the working drafts.

How do I cite such documents? Many of the working drafts don't even contain a
title page to extract information from.

Working drafts are available at https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: The 2014-11-19 version of c++ draft has document number and revise number ( I got it from download). These info should be enough for you to cite. Would you give a better example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would cite the current version of C++ standard, based on the **APA Style** (6th edition), in particular, based on the [APA guidelines for citing electronic sources (Web publications)](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/10), as follows:

ISO/IEC. (2014). *ISO International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) – Programming Language C++.* [Working draft]. Geneva, Switzerland: International Organization for Standardization (ISO). Retrieved from https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

**NOTE:** When the current standard will be finalized and published, the citation will have to be updated accordingly by removing "[Working draft.]" phrase and updating the year (i.e., 2015).

Comment: Ah ... ok, what does that "(E)" after 14882:2014 mean? To cite C++11 I'd then use 14882:2011, for C++03 14882:2003 and for C++98 14882:1998? (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards)

Comment: Moreover: Do I need to mirror their "withdrawn" state? (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ)

Comment: @DanielJour: I'm not 100% sure, but my best guess is that (E) indicates the _English language version_ of an ISO standard (I've seen that in some other ones). Another possibility, but less likely, is that it refers to an _early draft_ of a standard. The rest of the naming convention you figured out IMHO correctly.

Comment: @DanielJour: You can mention the withdrawn state for 2011 version, but I would prefer and recommend to reference the valid _working draft_, instead, especially since the differences are minor.

Comment: Which biblatex-entry-type do you use here?

Comment: @buhtz My answer above is general and doesn't imply LaTeX bibliography management. Having said that, consider this: 1) `biblatex` does not support the _standard_ type out-of-the-box (see p. 13 of [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)); 2) several `biblatex` type options can be used, depending on chosen/required style guide (e.g., _report_, _misc_, _custom_, _book_); 3) some relevant info on TeX SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203901/48376 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65637/48376.

Comment: Do they have a DOI?

Answer (score 2):

One can find nearly every citation for the C++ standards in BibTeX format here:

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.html

For example, here is the reference to the ISO C++98 standard:

```
@Book{ISO:1998:IIP,
  author =       "{ISO}",
  title =        "{ISO\slash IEC 14882:1998}: {Programming} languages
                 --- {C++}",
  publisher =    pub-ISO,
  address =      pub-ISO:adr,
  pages =        "732",
  day =          "1",
  month =        sep,
  year =         "1998",
  ISBN =         "????",
  ISBN-13 =      "????",
  LCCN =         "????",
  bibdate =      "Tue Dec 12 06:45:55 2000",
  bibsource =    "http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.bib;
                 http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/mathcw.bib",
  note =         "Available in electronic form for online purchase at
                 \path=http://webstore.ansi.org/= and
                 \path=http://www.cssinfo.com/=.",
  price =        "CHF 351, US\$18 (electronic), US\$252 (print);
                 US\$245.00",
  URL =          "http://webstore.ansi.org/ansidocstore/product.asp?sku=ISO%2FIEC+14882%2D1998;
                 http://webstore.ansi.org/ansidocstore/product.asp?sku=ISO%2FIEC+14882%3A1998;
                 http://www.iso.ch/cate/d25845.html;
                 https://webstore.ansi.org/",
  acknowledgement = ack-nhfb,
  xxISBN =       "none",
}
```

You can copy and paste this into your `.bib` file containing citations for LaTeX, which you should be using instead of Word anyway : ) You can use the `natbib` package to format it into whichever citation style you like.

Comment: I'd prefer citing one of the draft versions, because they are available for free ($0) instead of being quite expensive ($245). Unless it really, really has to be an official standard and not a draft that could have ended up as the standard.