# How to cite ISO standards?

Tags: citations

I am currently writing my PhD thesis and several times I cite various ISO standards. I am unsure what the correct way to format the bibliography entry for such documents is.

Currently I am doing something like:

> ISO (1997). ISO 4287 Geometrical Product Specifications (GPS) – Surface texture: Profile
>   method – Terms, definitions and surface texture parameters.

I'm using an author-year style so the entries normally look like

> Author (year) Title, Journal/publisher

Is there a better way to format this?

Comment: If you are using or plan to use _APA Style_, you might be interested in [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/45217/12391) to a related question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check out this blog entry on [Citing ISO Standards](http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/47.html) or this site on [Bibliographic Citation Standards and Schemes](http://dublincore.org/groups/citation/citstds.html)
As you can see there is no definitive answer to you question.

Maybe you ask your thesis advisor.

Comment: Please summarize the discussion here as those links may die.

Comment: Do you have an example of BibTex, where the corresponding fields are filled? ... Sry, found one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278558/31964

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how a standard is published, it should be cited either as an article, a book, or a technical report.

- If the standard is published as a journal article or has an associated journal article, e.g., then it should be cited as journal article.  Example: the BioBricks Assembly Standard.
- If the standard is published as a stand-alone book (e.g., being sold by a standards organization), then it should be cited as a book.  Example: many ANSI or ISO standards.
- If the standard is published through some other archival mechanism, then it should typically be cited as a technical report.  Example: IETF standards.

How exactly you format such citations then depends on the citation style that you are being asked to use (e.g., MLA, IEEE, Harvard).

Answer (score 2):

Using the C++ programming language as an example, one can find nearly every citation for the C++ standards in BibTeX format here:

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.html

For example, here is the reference to the ISO C++98 standard:

```
@Book{ISO:1998:IIP,
  author =       "{ISO}",
  title =        "{ISO\slash IEC 14882:1998}: {Programming} languages
                 --- {C++}",
  publisher =    pub-ISO,
  address =      pub-ISO:adr,
  pages =        "732",
  day =          "1",
  month =        sep,
  year =         "1998",
  ISBN =         "????",
  ISBN-13 =      "????",
  LCCN =         "????",
  bibdate =      "Tue Dec 12 06:45:55 2000",
  bibsource =    "http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.bib;
                 http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/mathcw.bib",
  note =         "Available in electronic form for online purchase at
                 \path=http://webstore.ansi.org/= and
                 \path=http://www.cssinfo.com/=.",
  price =        "CHF 351, US\$18 (electronic), US\$252 (print);
                 US\$245.00",
  URL =          "http://webstore.ansi.org/ansidocstore/product.asp?sku=ISO%2FIEC+14882%2D1998;
                 http://webstore.ansi.org/ansidocstore/product.asp?sku=ISO%2FIEC+14882%3A1998;
                 http://www.iso.ch/cate/d25845.html;
                 https://webstore.ansi.org/",
  acknowledgement = ack-nhfb,
  xxISBN =       "none",
}
```

You can copy and paste this into your `.bib` file containing citations for LaTeX, which you should be using instead of Word anyway : ) You can use the `natbib` package to format it into whichever citation style you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can cite it as follows:

Software engineering – Product quality – Part 4:
Quality in use metrics. ISO/IEC TR 9126-4:2004(E),
2004.

Website for the same is: https://www.iso.org/standard/39752.html