# bibtex entries for versions of the c++ standard

Tags: citations, code, bibtex

Where can I find BibTeX entries that help me cite a version of the C++ standard? In a paper I discuss the necessity of *trailing return types*, which became available in C++11. I want to be able to cite this version of the standard.

I came across a post on this site [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45215/how-do-i-correctly-cite-the-c-standard-or-its-drafts). Adam Erickson's answer provides a link to [this page](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.html) which appears to have entries for all versions of the standard. However, I wonder

1. if these are "outdated" in some sense because a few of the links are dead; and
2. which citation I should use (e.g. "ISO:2011:IIIa" or "ISO:2011:IIIb" or ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use a better search query. "cite ISO/IEC 14882:2011" gives as a first result this page: https://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/24b660c16d9a5ab0ad595b1555402c797/gron.

Here's the BibTeX entry:

```
@book{ISO:2012:III,
  added-at = {2012-10-08T01:13:47.000+0200},
  address = {Geneva, Switzerland},
  author = {{ISO}},
  bibdate = {Mon Dec 19 11:12:12 2011},
  bibsource = {http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/isostd.bib},
  biburl = {https://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/24b660c16d9a5ab0ad595b1555402c797/gron},
  day = 28,
  interhash = {ff5df6d7fa67f89d7d5ea964dab3e3c9},
  intrahash = {4b660c16d9a5ab0ad595b1555402c797},
  keywords = {C++ Specification Standard},
  month = feb,
  pages = {1338 (est.)},
  publisher = {International Organization for Standardization},
  remark = {Revises ISO/IEC 14882:2003.},
  timestamp = {2012-10-08T01:13:47.000+0200},
  title = {{ISO/IEC 14882:2011 Information technology --- Programming languages --- C++}},
  url = {http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372},
  year = 2012
}
```